# Proper Class Construction: Using Multiple Hard Dependencies

Tags: java, dependency-injection, constructor, parameter-passing, single-responsibility-principle

I'm trying to integrate Single Responsibility Principle into my Java code by refactoring large classes (2000+ lines) into smaller, cohesive classes (~200 lines). However I'm confused how to properly reduce coupling between classes, since **certain classes seem bound to be create multiple "hard dependencies" via the `new` keyword.**

I'm using dependency injection via constructors primarily, followed by setter methods, or methods which accept the dependency as a parameter and use it amonst other logic within the method body (not just a simple `this.val = val;` setter.

IntelliJ's automatic refactoring instantiates this newly extracted class and passes (injects) it with a `this` reference to the LoadController. If I have to refactor a 2000 line class, of course this auto-instantiation + injection will occur each time I extract a new class out. The following LoadController is a JavaFX controller class for the program's main stage, which acts as the starting point for various features:

```
public class LoadController{
        private final DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection(this); 
        private final UpdateLabels updateLabels = new UpdateLabels(this);
        private final OpenCloseMenu openCloseMenu= new OpenCloseMenu (this);
        private final CreateVBox createVBox= new CreateVBox (this, dbConnection);
        private final ...
        private final ...
}
```

Is this wrong? My understanding is that large, separate functions should be in their own class ... BUT some classes must have multiple hard dependencies like above, in order to "guide" the flow of logic between the use of various other classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing dependency injection into JavaFX controllers, you might want to look into using something like [Gluon Ignite](http://gluonhq.com/labs/ignite/) to assist you.

> Gluon Ignite allows developers to use popular dependency injection frameworks in their JavaFX applications, including inside their FXML controllers. Gluon Ignite creates a common abstraction over several popular dependency injection frameworks

The injection framework you choose to use (e.g. Guice or Spring) will be responsible for creating the injectable components (e.g. you don't invoke `new`) and injecting the relevant references into your code, (e.g. you don't need to write `dbConnection = <some value>`).  The injection framework will have extensive documentation and blog articles on how it works and how it may best be used, so full discussion of that is outside the scope of this answer.

An alternate to Gluon Ignite is [afterburner.fx](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com), which is similar but uses a small custom implementation for [@Inject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/package-summary.html), so is more lightweight (and a little less powerful), then the more established dependency injection frameworks (very simple to use though).

This is just one option, there are other ways you can handle this, but seeing as you state that you wish to perform dependency injection with JavaFX, it seems to make sense of proven frameworks to do this rather than try to roll your own implementation.

> some classes must have multiple hard dependencies like above, in order to "guide" the flow of logic between the use of various other classes.

Using something like Guice you provide a module that defines bindings between interface types and implementations.  These bindings tell Guice how to construct the dependencies, so you don't need to hard code the dependencies in your classes.  See the BillingModule in the [Guice getting started guide](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted) for a module example.  If you need multiple instances of injectable objects, you can use [Providers](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods) in Guice.  Spring has similar concepts, but different names.

---

Deciding on whether or not to use a dependency injection framework is a tradeoff between the work you would need to do if there was no injection framework vs the additional time and complexity of integrating the framework into your application.  so the decision of whether or not to use one needs to be an architectural decision that you make, there is not a generic right or wrong answer for every application on whether use of such frameworks is justified.

> I decide that using an injection framework is superfluous for my requirements, then I am not doing anything inherently incorrect by having multiple hard dependencies in some classes, as shown above?

Well the dependencies need to be defined somewhere.  Either in an inferred or centralized location such as dependency injection systems use or local to given classes as you might determine from a traditional [responsibility driven design approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsibility-driven_design).  So you are not necessarily doing anything wrong by having hard dependencies.  Abstract decoupling patterns such as dependency injection aren't always required.

The trick is determining what dependencies to have where and how to manage them.  Often it is just obvious and falls out naturally from the problem domain, sometimes techniques such as [CRC modeling](http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/crcModel.htm) can help structure dependencies.

Related article:

- [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).

> My assumption is that I can refactor my large classes into smaller, cohesive classes with some of these classes having multiple hard dependencies, using new.

Yes, you can certainly do that.

> Can an injection framework be integrated later on in a project's life, rather than early on when it may not be required yet?

Yes it can.  It will be a bit of work to do so, but if the application is well structured, not all that difficult.  It is more difficult to go the other way and try to remove usage of a dependency injection framework from applications and libraries that are already based on it.

Related:

- [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

Comment: Thanks jewelsea, so you're saying that if I decide that using an injection framework is superfluous for my requirements, then I am *not* doing anything inherently incorrect by having multiple hard dependencies in some classes, as shown above? My assumption is that I can refactor my large classes into smaller, cohesive classes with some of these classes having multiple hard dependencies, using `new`. Can an injection framework be integrated later on in a project's life, rather than early on when it may not be required yet?